# ObservableCollection or List data bind with comboBox using MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have ObservableCollection items i want to bind this data to my comboBox. 
How to bind data with comboBox?
I am using MVVM pattern so suggest me how to bind data using MVVM pattern

I am trying to do this code but not working properly..
**In my XAML PAGE:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" 
          DisplayMemberPath="CardTypeName" 
          SelectedValuePath="CardTypeID" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combodata}">    
</ComboBox>
```

**In my ViewModel**
(`Card` is my model)

```
 public ObservableCollection<Card> combodata = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
 foreach (var item in App.db.States)
 {
     Card c = new Card(item.StateName, item.StateID);
     combodata.Add(c);
 }
```

How to bind this combodata to my comboBox - what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

At first: your `combodata` has **private** access modifier instead of **public**. At second: `combodata` must be **property** but not the **field**. And you'd better add INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to you class.

Comment: it's still a field. Change it to `public ObservableCollection<Card> combodata { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind to a public property of the view model that should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here's what you should do:

View:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" DisplayMemberPath="CardTypeName" SelectedValuePath="CardTypeID" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboData}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Card> comboData;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<Card> ComboData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.comboData;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.comboData != value)
                {
                    this.comboData = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboData");
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
```

*EDIT*: you'll also need to set the `DataContext` property of your view. The simple way is to affect the instance of your ViewModel to the `DataContext` property in the code-behind of your view.

Comment: Ashwin, try to check DataContext property.

Answer (score 2):

```
private ObservableCollection<Card> _combodata;
Public ObservableCollection<Card> comboData
{
   get
   {
      if (_combodata == null)
         _combodata = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
      return _combodata;
   }
   set
   {
       if (value != _combodata)
           _combodata = value;
   }
}


<ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" 
      DisplayMemberPath="CardTypeName" 
      SelectedValuePath="CardTypeID" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=comboData}">    
</ComboBox>
```

*And don't forget to set a DataContext property.*

Comment: in datacontext which data i give?

Comment: you should set DataContext property of your combobox or his ascendent parents to your viewmodel object which contains ObservableCollection<Card> comboData

Answer (score 2):

There are following problems with the code.

1.You can not bind to private field or property. It should be public property.

2.You only provided  `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combodata}"` but did not provide a source. Where does combodata come from ?

ObservableCollection has nothing to do unless your combo box items doe not change once filled. In this case List can work well.

To make it work, Change your combodata to public property as

```
public ObservableCollection<Card> combodata {get;set;}
```

then,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" 
          DisplayMemberPath="CardTypeName" 
          SelectedValuePath="CardTypeID" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combodata}" ElementName=mainWindow>    
</ComboBox>
```

by specifying ElementName you are telling WPF binding engine to look for the combodata property of the mainWindow class.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is your ComboBox's `DataContext` is not set to an instance of your ViewModel

I often use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to debug DataContext problems with the application. It allows you to view your Visual Tree, and see what the DataContext is for all controls.

The DataContext is the data your UI is bound to. Usually the DataContext is set higher up in the Visual Tree, such as on the Window object, although as an example the following line of code would set the ComboBox's DataContext to a new instance of your ViewModel, and then your ComboBox should be able to find the `combodata` collection to bind to it.

```
comobo1.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

Also, change your `combodata` from a `Field` (no get/set accessor methods) to a `Property` (see [Dmitriy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668014/302677) for an example)

Comment: but my combo1 is in dataTemplate not directly using in my xaml. so i cannot get comboBox in my code behind for give the datacontext to my combobox

Comment: I am getting data if i put my combobox out of dataTemplate but I cannot get data in dataTemplate how i use all code is running out of datatemplate but not in dataTemplate

Comment: @Ashwin Set the DataContext of whatever control is in the UI that contains the templated ComboBox then. The ComboBox will inherit it's DataContext from that control when it gets Rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to a public property.  In your example, combodata is private.

Comment: you should bind it to public (!) property (!). In your code you trying bind to public field.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer is :

**In XAML PAGE":**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="comboBoxCollection" Source="{Binding comboData}"></CollectionViewSource>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
            <Grid MinHeight="25">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" DisplayMemberPath="CardTypeName"   SelectedValuePath="CardTypeID" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxCollection }}">
                    </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
```

**In ViewModel:**

```
 private ObservableCollection<Card> _combodata;

        public ObservableCollection<Card> comboData
        {
            get
            {
                if (_combodata == null)
                    _combodata = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
                return _combodata;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _combodata)
                    _combodata = value;
            }
        }

  if (_objCardField.FieldTag == "State") 
                {
                    cards = new Cards();
                    foreach (var item in App.db.States)
                    {
                        Card c = new Card(item.StateName, item.StateID);
                        comboData.Add(c);
                    }
                }
```